# Numba is running a lot slower than the raw Python

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm new to using Numba and keen to try and understand how it works.

I built a binary search function:

```
def binarysearch(alist, item):
        first = 0
        last = len(alist) - 1
        found = False

        while first<=last:
            midpoint = (first + last)//2            
            if alist[midpoint] == item:
                return midpoint
            else:
                if item < alist[midpoint]:
                    last = midpoint-1
                else:
                    first = midpoint+1  
        return -1
```

And if I run this as follows:

```
l = list(range(10000000))

%timeit
binarysearch(l,5000)
```

I get:
`4.88 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

If I do the same but use `@numba.njit`, I get:
`19.8 s ± 533 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Any ideas for how to get the improvements of Numba?

versions:
Python: 3.6.3
Numba:  0.40.0

Comment: That’s interesting. Have you tried a typed array instead of a list? Also maybe profile it by having it search for random numbers instead of always the same one. Could you count the number of iterations? 19s seems awfully slow for numba.

Comment: Just tried:
```
import random
from array import array
l = array('i',range(10000000))
x = random.randint(0,10000000)
```
and got a time of:
```531 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)```
and for the raw python:
```5.57 µs ± 282 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)```
So that seems to have worked...

Comment: I’m glad I was able to help.

Comment: Any idea why lists don't work and array's do? Even with typing?

Comment: Not really. In Python, list items can be of arbitrary type and size, it might be interesting on reading up on those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171491/binary-layout-of-python-lists. Numba might have difficulties optimizing that. OTOH the memory address of each item in a numpy array/typed array/etc. is know before the loop even starts, so I’d assume this makes for way less overhead.